# Z3 unsigned variables - simplify

Tags: c, constraints, z3, unsigned, smt

I have the following constraint (constr) I want to simplify:

4p+3q<=-10+r AND 4p+3q<=-12+r

p (and similar for r) is created as follows:

```
Z3_ast p;
Z3_sort ty = Z3_mk_int_sort(ctx)
Z3_symbol s = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "p");
p = Z3_mk_const(ctx, s, ty)
```

If i do

```
Z3_simplify(ctx, constr)
```

Nothing changes as p and r are integers.

How can I encode the knowledge that p an r are natural numbers (unsigned)?

Simply adding the constraint p >= 0 AND r >= 0 will not help in the context of simplifying my constraint (but of course helps when seeking a solution).

To clarify,

4p+3q<=-10+r AND 4p+3q<=-12+r

should be reduced to:

4p+3q<=-12+r

As it is the hardest to fulfill (implies the other).

**UPDATE:**
Tried the solution by Taylor on the constraint and it works.
When I try to use the same technique for the following different (somewhat)-pretty-printed constraint:

> (([(false AND (0<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND false)) OR (0<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p  AND [(0+0epsilon+q+0p<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND (0+0epsilon+q+0p<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND [false OR 0+0epsilon+0q+p<=7+0epsilon+0q+0p])) OR (false AND false) OR (false AND false)])] AND [(false AND (0<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND false)) OR (0<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND [(0+0epsilon+q+0p<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND (0+0epsilon+q+0p<=5+0epsilon+0q+0p AND [false OR 0+0epsilon+0q+p<=7+0epsilon+0q+0p])) OR (false AND false) OR (false AND false)])]) AND epsilon>=0 AND q>=0 AND p>=0)

By Z3_simplify this is reduced to

> (q<=5 AND p<=7 AND epsilon>=0 AND q>=0 AND p>=0)

If I create a tactic using ctx-solver-simplify together with a goal and use Z3_apply_result_to_string, I get the following:

```
(goals
(goal
  (let ((a!1 (+ 5 (* 0 epsilon) (* 0 q) (* 0 p)))
        (a!3 (or false
                 (<= (+ 0 (* 0 epsilon) (* 0 q) p)
                     (+ 7 (* 0 epsilon) (* 0 q) (* 0 p))))))
  (let ((a!2 (<= (+ 0 (* 0 epsilon) q (* 0 p)) a!1)))
    (or (and false (<= 0 a!1) false)
        (and (<= 0 a!1)
             (or (and a!2 a!2 a!3) (and false false) (and false false))))))
  (>= epsilon 0)
  (>= q 0)
  (>= p 0))
)
```

What can I do to get a simple representation like the one for Z3_simplify?

Comment: Are you concerned if `4p+3q` or `-10+r` overflow?

Comment: There is no notion of overflow here: they are integers / natural numbers in the mathematical sense (i.e., may go to infinity) and are represented as symbolic mathematical objects within Z3/SMT instead of something with finite range (such as a 32-bit int, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example, this can be done using the strongest simplifier, `ctx-solver-simplify`, although note that in general this could transform your equations.  Here is your example (rise4fun link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tw0t ):

```
(declare-fun p () Int)
(declare-fun q () Int)
(declare-fun r () Int)

(assert (and (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (- r 10)) (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (- r 12))))

(apply ctx-solver-simplify)

(apply (then simplify ctx-simplify ctx-solver-simplify))

; (help-tactic)
```

Output:

```
(goals
(goal
  (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (+ r (* (- 1) 12)))
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)
(goals
(goal
  (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (+ (- 12) r))
  :precision precise :depth 3)
)
```

You can use the tactics via the C API as well.

You can add the natural number constraint as well:

```
(assert (and (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (- r 10)) (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (- r 12))))
(assert (>= p 0))
(assert (>= r 0))
(apply ctx-solver-simplify)
(apply (then simplify ctx-simplify ctx-solver-simplify))
```

Output:

```
(goals
(goal
  (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (+ r (* (- 1) 12)))
  (>= p 0)
  (>= r 0)
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)
(goals
(goal
  (<= (+ (* 4 p) (* 3 q)) (+ (- 12) r))
  (>= p 0)
  (>= r 0)
  :precision precise :depth 3)
)
```

UPDATE:

You probably just need to iterate over the appropriate subgoals after applying the simplification tactics to get the formulas out if you need the simplified ones for something, see, e.g. `Z3_apply_result_get_subgoal`:

http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga63813eb4cc7865f0cf714e1eff0e0c64

When I tried this tactic on your new constraint, it also returns the simplified answer you stated (rise4fun link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/T1TZ ):

```
(declare-fun epsilon () Int)
(declare-fun q () Int)
(declare-fun p () Int)

(assert (and  (let ((a!1 (+ 5 (* 0 epsilon) (* 0 q) (* 0 p)))
        (a!3 (or false
                 (<= (+ 0 (* 0 epsilon) (* 0 q) p)
                     (+ 7 (* 0 epsilon) (* 0 q) (* 0 p))))))
  (let ((a!2 (<= (+ 0 (* 0 epsilon) q (* 0 p)) a!1)))
    (or (and false (<= 0 a!1) false)
        (and (<= 0 a!1)
             (or (and a!2 a!2 a!3) (and false false) (and false false))))))
  (>= epsilon 0)
  (>= q 0)
  (>= p 0)))

(apply (then simplify ctx-simplify ctx-solver-simplify))
```

which yields

```
(goals
(goal
  (<= q 5)
  (>= epsilon 0)
  (>= q 0)
  (>= p 0)
  (<= p 7)
  :precision precise :depth 3)
)
```